# Send account confirmation email to specific customer group in magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to send an account confirmation email  to a specific customer group with specific customer domain @example.com

For that, I need to override the **sendEmailConfirmation()** function in my app/code module from file (vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm looking for same functionality. Can anyone help please ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156921)

Comment: I looking for the same. if anyone has the answer please comment here